# Visual Basic: Save in same folder as Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VB, so this is probably a very easy one.  I'm creating a Word document from an Excel spreadsheet, and would like the Word doc to save in the same folder location as the spreadsheet.

I'm using the code:
`.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & Range("C8").Text & ".docx"`
Which I though would work, but it saves it in teh directory up from the location.

I.e. the spreadsheet is in `C:/User/Documents/MySpreadsheet`.  But the Word doc would be saved in `C:/User/Documents`.

I also made a message popup to display `ThisWorkbook.Path` which comes up with the Spreadsheet path, so I know that's right!

I also don't think I've done the naming right, as I would like it to be named the text in cell C8.  But it's actually the 'Documents' folder name with the text in C8 added on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) and and add this line to your code:

```
debug.print ThisWorkbook.Path & Range("C8").Text & ".docx"
```

You will see if your path is correct. In particular, if you have "\" between folder path and filename.

Comment: Thanks!  New it would be something simple.  Adding the \ fixed it.